# SQL substr query

Tags: sql, plsql

I need to understand this query as best as possible, thanks

```
substr(b_Aplicacion,1,4) 
|| '-' 
|| substr(b_Aplicacion,5,2) 
|| '-' 
|| substr(b_Aplicacion,7,2)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you're aware of how the `substr()` function works. (If not, [here's an explanation](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Oracle/0420__PL-SQL-Data-Types/SUBSTR.htm).)

In PLSQL `||` is a string concatenation operator.

Example: `'left' || ' - ' || 'right'` evaluates to `'left - right'`

Your example looks like it's reformatting a string that probably is a date like `20120102` into `2012-01-02`

Comment: Why? I need to understand why this function is used in this way, give a good structured example

Comment: How can I make this more clear? `||` is an operator that concatenates the left string to the right string. So `'a ' || 'plus' || ' b'` becomes `'a plus b'`. Here's another example: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Oracle/0460__PL-SQL-Operators/StringOperators.htm

Answer (score 2):

This expression inserts dashes into the string after the 4-th and 6-th position, and throws away characters after the 8-th position. For example, `abcdefghijkl` becomes `abcd-ef-gh`.

Substr cuts out three parts from the string: `abcd`, `ef`, and `gh` in my example. `|| '-' ||` glues the parts back together, inserting dashes in between. `||` between two string expressions represent *concatenation*, i.e. it makes one string by gluing the part on its left to the part on its right.

Comment: please some more details! i need to see whay the function ||'-'|| is after each example., etc

Answer (score 1):

[substr( string, start_position, [ length ] )](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/substr.php) is performed like this:

- string is the source string.
- start_position is the position for extraction. The first position in the string is always 1.
- length is optional. It is the number of characters to extract. If this parameter is omitted, substr will return the entire string.

The `||` represents `concatenation`.

---

So that `query` is separating the placcing a '-' character after 4th and 6th positions.

---

**For example**, if you have `20121221` as `b_Aplicacion` that query will return `2011-12-21`.